# Why is PrimeGenerator class generates one more number than what I want?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have some issues with this prime generator class.

This code is printing one more prime number.
for example when the input is 25, I get in the answer

```
2       3       5       7       11      
13      17      19      23      29
```

(with an additional prime 29 that I don't want)

I think it is due to --> while(primeGenerator.getCurrentPrime() < input) in the main class.

But how to fix this exactly?

These are my code snippets

```
public class PrimeGeneratorTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // ask for the input from the user
    System.out.print("Enter the input: ");
    int input = in.nextInt();

    // create a prime generator object
    PrimeGenerator primeGenerator = new PrimeGenerator(input);

    // create a counter for the number of columns in a line
    int n = 0;
    // Check if the current prime number is less than the upper limit
    while (primeGenerator.getCurrentPrime() < input){

        System.out.printf("%-8d",primeGenerator.nextPrime());
        n++;

        //start a new line for each 5 columns
        if (n % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the PrimeGenerator class

```
public class PrimeGenerator {

private int upperLimit;
private int prime;

/**
 * Constructs a prime generator object
 * @param upperLimit the upper limit of the prime numbers
 */
public PrimeGenerator(int upperLimit){
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
    prime = 2;
}

/**
 * Checks if the current iterating number is prime or not
 * @return true if prime
 *         false if not prime
 */
public boolean isPrime(){
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < prime ; i++){
        if (prime % i == 0){
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}

/**
 * Returns the next prime number
 * @return the next prime number
 */
public int nextPrime(){
    int currentPrime = 2;
    while(!isPrime()){
        prime ++;
    }
    currentPrime = prime;
    prime ++;
    return currentPrime;

}//nextPrime

/**
 * Returns the current iterating prime number
 * @return current iterating prime number
 */
public int getCurrentPrime() {
    return prime;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `while (currentPrime < input) print nextPrime` - can you see the problem here?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak This is checking for the current prime and then printing the next prime. So, for example, I think that the while loop has checked if 23 is less than 25, true, so it printed the next prime. But how to fix this in an easy step?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a big improvement you could make is to only divide the prime-possible number up to (and including) the square root of the number: `for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(prime); i++)`. This will save a ton of iterations when dealing with larger numbers.

Comment: @MikeBruesch I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not outputting the current prime which is smaller than the input, but the next prime which may be anything far higher than your input.

This might get you closer:

```
System.out.printf("%-8d",primeGenerator.currentPrime());
primeGenerator.nextPrime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inspection is correct,

The following loop is worked for 23 < 25 and then next prime is calculated as 29 and it is printed.

```
  while (primeGenerator.primeGenerator.nextPrime() < input) // It does not limit 23
```

Then solution could be in loop condition:

```
while (primeGenerator.nextPrime() < input)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but with an additional modification in the getCurrentPrime method. I am returning prime - 1 and that's going fine. But I think this solution is somehow inconvenient and the nextPrime method should be modified also with the act of updating the prime variable (It's actually holding the actual prime number+1). Could you help me please? @kaan